Wrong mask applied when installing wordpress
I have a webdirectory (volleybal_wijchen) html with acl:
# file: volleybal_wijchen/
# owner: volleybal-wijchen
# group: webusers
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

If i create a directory in it manually i get a directory with (correct):
# file: test/
# owner: volleybal-wijchen
# group: webusers
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

But if i do:
wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz
getfacl wordpress/wp-admin

I get:
# file: wordpress/wp-admin
# owner: volleybal-wijchen
# group: webusers
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx               **#effective:r-x** (i do not want this)
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

It looks as if a different mask is applied but i have no clue as to why. Can anyone see what i am doing wrong? I want to stick to default acl and prevent manually applying chmod and chown to directories.
i have tried:
tar --no-acls --no-selinux --no-xattrs -xvf

